# Mapping array of objects contain also a array of objects to as multiple lines in mat-table angular material

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an formations array of objects in this structure

```
formations= [ 
  {
    id: 100
    course: 'Angular',
    dateCreation:01/08/2020,
    students: [
      {id: 236, name: 'Ahmed', enrolled_date: '', email: ''},
      {id: 265, name: 'Sara', enrolled_date: '', email: ''},
      {id: 270, name: 'Caroll', enrolled_date: '', email: ''}
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 101,
    course: 'React',
    dateCreation: 06/03/2016,
    students: [
      {id: 370, name: 'Jean', enrolled_date: '', email: ''},
      {id: 371, name: 'Arnold', enrolled_date: '', email: ''},
      {id: 372, name: 'Matthieu', enrolled_date: '', email: ''}
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 102,
    course: 'React Native',
    dateCreation: 09/09/2019,
    students: [
      {id: 450, name: 'Samia', enrolled_date: '', email: ''},
      {id: 265, name: 'Sara', enrolled_date: '', email: ''},
      {id: 460, name: 'Georges', enrolled_date: '', email: ''}
    ]
  }
]
```

and my objective is to display this formations array in a mat table like this :

| Course | dateCreation | Name | Enrolled Date | Email |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Angular | 01/08/2020 | Ahmad |  |  |
| Angular | 01/08/2020 | Sara |  |  |
| Angular | 01/08/2020 | Caroll |  |  |
| REACT | 06/03/2016 | Jean |  |  |
| REACT | 06/03/2016 | Arnold |  |  |
| REACT | 06/03/2016 | Matthieu |  |  |
| REACT NATIVE | 09/09/2019 | Samia |  |  |
| REACT NATIVE | 09/09/2019 | Sara |  |  |
| REACT NATIVE | 09/09/2019 | Georges |  |  |

in my component.ts I have :

```
dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Formation>();

ngOnInit(): void {
    this._formationService.getFormations().subscribe(formations => {
      this.dataSource.data = formations;      
    });
```

where :

```
Formation {
    id: number,
    titre: string,
    dateDebut: Moment,
    dateFin: Moment,
    lieu: string,
    description: string,     
    list_participants: Participant[],
    dateCreation: Moment
}
```

and in template :

```
    <mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">    

        <!-- titre Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="titre">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Course </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.titre}} </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>


        <!-- Date Creation Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="dateCreation">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> dateCreation </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.dateCreation | amDateFormat:'LL'}} </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>


                  
        <!--   Name student Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="nameStudent">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Name </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> 
            <span *ngFor="let item of row.list_participants">{{item.name}}</span>
            </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
        
        <!--   Enrolled Date student Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="enrolled_dateStudent">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Enrolled Date </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> 
            <span *ngFor="let item of row.list_participants">{{item.enrolled_date| amDateFormat:'LL'}}</span>
            </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
        
        <!--   Email student Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="emailStudent">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Email </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> 
            <span *ngFor="let item of row.list_participants">{{item.email}}</span>
            </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
        
        

        <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns ; sticky:true"></mat-header-row>
        <mat-row class="formation-row" *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
      </mat-table>
```

Thank you for any help or suggestion

Answer (score 0):

The solution is :

```
list: any[] = [];

ngOnInit(): void {
    this._formationService.getFormations().subscribe(formations => {
      
      formations.forEach (formation => {

        formation.students.forEach(student=> {
          this.list.push({
            id: formation.id,
            course: formation.course,
            dateCreation: formation.dateCreation,
            _id: student.id,
            name: student.name,
            enrolled_date: student.enrolled_date,            
            email: student.email
          });     
    });
```

in the template just put :

```
    <mat-table [dataSource]="list">
```